# Visual studio (17.3.4) update causes xamarin forms solution to go in an infinite loop

Tags: forms, xamarin

I've updated my visual studio 2022 to the latest version and now its an infinite loop trying to load my xamarin forms projects file.
It constantly tries to restore csprojects and intellisense.
I have already checked the box to install xamarin
I have uninstalled reinstalled
I have checked if there are any .net sdks are installed elsewhere

It's been 2 days I'm trying to fix this problem with no luck.

Comment: For xamarin forms solution to go in an infinite loop, may I know some specific error codes？